# React Native how can I find if user denied permissions in app settings

Tags: permissions, android-permissions, react-native

I am developing a React Native app which needs permission of `location` and `storage`. I've added needed permissions to `AndroidManifest.xml` and by default permissions are granted after app installation.

But if use try to deny the permissions from app settings page (as you can see in the screenshot below), the `PermissionsAndroid.request` can not find the permissions are denied and always returns `authorized`.

[image]

Is there any way to find if user has denied the permissions after app installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [this library](https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions) for the purpose, and more specifically 
from the example:

```
Permissions.checkMultiple(['camera', 'photo'])
  .then(response => {
    //response is an object mapping type to permission
    this.setState({
      cameraPermission: response.camera,
      photoPermission: response.photo,
    })
  });
```

Comment: I am using the same library, but it returns `authorized` event if user has denied access to location and storage in app setting page @alexander-vitanov

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions/issues/167

Comment: Also, specifically for android permissions you can refer to the official docs here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid.html

Comment: I've changed my targetSdkVersion to 23 and the problem fixed @alexander-vitanov